# How to create a Listview so that clicking on each list item will open different activity?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a List view. I want to click on each list item and it would open different activity. Actually, I wrote the code, but its not working. My coding skills are unable to handle the issue. How to create a Hahmap with a string and a class pair and then put that into ArrayAdapter . Can any one please show me the code?

ListViewAcivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_activity);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        HashMap<String, Class> hashMap=new HashMap<String, Class>();


         hashMap.put("A Function", MActivity.class);
         hashMap.put("B Function",AActivity.class);
         hashMap.put("c Function",XActivity.class);
         hashMap.put("D Function",ZActivity.class);
         hashMap.put("E Function", PActivity.class);
         hashMap.put("F Function", QActivity.class);


        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data
```

//error is here...... // this constructor can not be solved. //I don't know how to use    //String, Class pair with Array Adapter.

```
  ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,Class>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,Class>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, hashMap);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch(itemPosition){
                    case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, MActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, AActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity1);
                        break;
                    case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, XActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);
                        break;
                    case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ZActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity3);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, PActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity4);
                        break;
                    case 5:  Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, QActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity5);
                        break;


                }

            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onClick(View v){
            };
        });}
}
```

main_screen_Activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Static example for the functionality you are asking for.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialize the list view
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);

        //Add the List data
        //as the array is stored starting with 0, the Layouts will be having 0th position, Intents being 1 and so on..
        String[] sessiontuts = new String[]{"Activity 1", "Activity2"};

        //use the Simple array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,sessiontuts);

        //now to bind the data to list, just set the adapter we just created to the listview,
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

        //we need to have click listner on the particular item,
        //all the items in list will have a position starting from 0 to n,
        //so, write the intent code to launch particular activity depending on list item position
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                //using switch case, to check the condition.
                switch (pos){
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Act1.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Act2.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) expects an **array** or a **List** of Objects to display. So you need to provide an array/list

What makes you think that it can deal with a **Map**? Lists/arrays represent sequences of things; whereas maps represent, well a mapping from some kind of thingy to some other thingy.

In other words: you can't pass a map object.

Simply pass a list or an array containing the strings you want to display ("Medical Reminders", ... ).

But there is value in having that map; you just need to change your code a bit:

First, you can use the **keys** of the map as input when creating the ArrayAdapter, like this:

```
List<String> arrayItems = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.keySet());
```

And then, in `onClickItem()` you do **not** need to retrieve the index - because you already have that map that tells you which class belongs to which string! Meaning: the ListView gives you the selected item as **string**, and `hashMap` maps all possible strings to the corresponding activity class!

So, you can throw away your whole "switch" code and instead do something like:

```
String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
Class classForSelectedValue = hashMap.get(itemValue);
Intent activity = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, classForSelectedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification . Now, I got the Idea. I am trying to fix it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, and feel free to accept my answer if it gave you what you were looking for.